# Where are the can.h and can/raw.h header files in Cygwin?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, cygwin, can-bus

I wrote a little tool to display CAN messages based on SocketCAN. Trying to compile it in Cygwin results in an error indicating that gcc can't find the mentioned header files.
In which directory or package are these files?

Comment: Have you installed the relevant package at all?

Comment: Basically I am asking for what the relevant package is. Which Cygwin package contains these headers?

Comment: SocketCAN appears to be a Linux thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought to look for hint on the cygwin Website ?

The search feature is at:
https://cygwin.com/packages/

However I doubt that cygwin posses such low level functionality

```
$ cygcheck -p can/raw.h
Found 0 matches for can/raw.h
```

and you need to use Linux
https://github.com/linux-can/can-utils